# WordPress on OpenShift online

Tags: openshift

I am trying to create a WordPress application in OpenShift Online. I found an online instruction for [OpenShift Online V3](https://blog.openshift.com/running-wordpress-easy-way/), but it does not seem to be up to date. Specifically in the section "Deploying WordPress", it advised that in order to create a new WordPress application:

```
To deploy a fresh WordPress instance, from the web console select 
Add to Project. Under Browse Catalog, select PHP. You should be able 
to see options for deploying WordPress.
```

But I could not find "options for deploying WordPress".

Does OpenShift still support WordPress? If it does may someone suggest instructions on how to achieve it?

Comment: Describe the problem/error you are encountering. It is impossible to guess if don't provide details.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.

Comment: The instruction: https://blog.openshift.com/running-wordpress-easy-way/

Comment: Go 'Add to Project -> Select from Project'. The OpenShift web console changed a bit in where things are, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

The steps I took to create a WordPress application on OpenShift Online platform:

1. Follow the steps in the [OpenShift blog](https://blog.openshift.com/running-wordpress-easy-way/) to load the WordPress templates into your project.
2. Creating a WordPress app:

   a. Go to the OpenShift Web Console, click "Select from project".

   b. In the next screen, select the project to which the WordPress templates were just loaded. Two options will be available.